# ReSharper rules vs Visual Studio 2013 code analysis

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have tried to find any comparison matrix between ReSharper inspections (1400+) and Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis (230).

I wonder which rules we will miss if we continue to use resharper 8.1 and skip vs 2013 code analysis.

Comment: Why do you think you have to miss one of them? You can simply enable both.

Comment: In out CI environment we do not want to run duplicate controls to speed up feedback loop. Code Analysis also makes VS slow...